# Table with merged cells, multi-index and text wrap

Tags: tables

I'd like to have a table that looks like this. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g476E.png) a link to open the image in another tab.

[image: table]

What matters to me is the structure. The formatting is just to show what I'd like to stand out from the rest in some way.

How do I:

1. Make sure text is wrapped when the data has over a specific length.
2. Use a multicolumn for the bottom right cells, as per the image?

Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
 % Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{Outer index 1} & Inner index 1.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & Inner index 1.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\ 
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{Outer index 2} & Inner index 2.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & Inner index 2.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \hline
            \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 3} &  Inner index 3.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.3 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.4 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.5 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.5 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            &Inner index 3.6 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Better formatting is welcome. Feel free to add your own touch.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think `multicolumn` is what you want. Anyway, please add a minimal working example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have acmoplished so far to illustrate your problem?

Comment: @whoami: Please add the code directly to your question (by using the edit button). Content from external sites might be removed in the future which makes a question that relies on externally shown code unusable for future readers.

Comment: @leandriis My code wasn't a minimal example yet, that's why I didn't add it to the question. I now have a minimal example and I'm about to add it. Thank you for your guideance.

Comment: @whoami: I have removed the `pgfplotstable` and `threeparttable` tags from your question as you do not use the corresponding packages in your MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following includes:

- `tabularx` for `X` type columns and a table that fits the textwidth
- `\multicolumn`  for the cells spanning 2 columns
- adjusted values of `\multirow` to vertically center the text in the first column
- replaced `center` environment by `\centering` as the former adds additional white space around the table
- used horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package for improved spacing.

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt]{article}

  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{table}[ht]
      \centering
          \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
              \toprule
              \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 1} & Inner index 1.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
              & Inner index 1.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\ 
              \midrule
              \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 2} & Inner index 2.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
              & Inner index 2.2 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
              \midrule
              \multirow{9}{*}{Outer index 3} &  Inner index 3.1 & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
              &Inner index 3.2 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
              &Inner index 3.3 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
              \bottomrule
          \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

---

Here, I have also used `multirow` for the contents of the second column:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 1} & \multirow{3}{*}{Inner index 1.1} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & \multirow{3}{*}{Inner index 1.2} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\ 
            \midrule
            \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 2} & \multirow{3}{*}{Inner index 2.1} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & \multirow{3}{*}{Inner index 2.2} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \midrule
            \multirow{9}{*}{Outer index 3} &  \multirow{3}{*}{Inner index 3.1} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & \multirow{3}{*}{Inner index 3.2} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            & \multirow{3}{*}{Inner index 3.3} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In oder to vertically center the text in the second column, you could also use the `makecell` package in combination with vertically centered `X` type columns as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
            \toprule
            \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 1} & \makecell[cc]{Inner index 1.1} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & \makecell[cc]{Inner index 1.2} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\ 
            \midrule
            \multirow{6}{*}{Outer index 2} & \makecell[cc]{Inner index 2.1} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & \makecell[cc]{Inner index 2.2} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            \midrule
            \multirow{9}{*}{Outer index 3} &  \makecell[cc]{Inner index 3.1} & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped. & Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.\\
            & \makecell[cc]{Inner index 3.2} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            & \makecell[cc]{Inner index 3.3} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}{ Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.  Text data placeholder. May be long enough that it needs to be wrapped.}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to vertically center the first two columns?

Comment: For the contents of the second column use `\multirow{3}{*}{<your text>}`. If you add more rows you might need to adjust the number in the first argument of `multirow` in the first column accordingly.

Comment: Isn't that what is already being done? They aren't centered for me.

Comment: @whoami: I have added a second MWE showing how to vertically center the contents of the second column. I have also added images of the output I obtain from the two different examples.

Comment: Thanks. But won't this potentially fail to be centered when the text is different? Because the text I'm using is different and I don't want to rely on my very bad eyes to assess what value centers the indices.

Comment: @whoami: This is correct. I have added a different variant using a more automated approach with the `makecell` package.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying to make the last two columns just a little wider. How can I tweak this? I'm basically trying to make it so that an entry that is 41 characters long doesn't get wrapped.

Comment: Currently the table is as wide as the textwidth. If you need more space but don't want the table to exceed the textwidth, you could a) split the contents of the first two columns over multiple rows b) decrease the font size of the table using `\small` or c) use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}` (or a different length)  to slightly decrease the horizontal space between the columns.